# Why does Nodemon is crushing after clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, nodemon

**Javascript Code**
As you can  see my button has a event handeler but when I click on the stock update button node nodemon crushed. I don't know why it's happening.

```
  const Inventory = ({ inventory }) => {
  const { name, img, _id, price, description, quantity,suplierName } = inventory; 
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const navigateToInventories = id =>{
  navigate('/allinventory/' + id)
  }
  return (
        <div className='Row gx-5' style={{ width: '18rem',marginRight:'40px', 
           marginLeft:"40px" ,marginBottom:"40px"}} >
          <div className='Col-lg-3 '>
          <CardGroup className='ms-5 mt-3' style={{ width: '300px ', height:'560px'}}>
            <Card className='mt-4'>
              <Card.Img style={{ width: '300px' }} variant="top" src={img} />
              <Card.Body >
                <Card.Title>{name}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  {description}
                </Card.Text>
                <Card.Text>
                 Price :{price}
                </Card.Text>
                <Card.Text>
                 Quantity : {quantity}
                </Card.Text>
                <Card.Text>
                 Suplier Name  : {suplierName}
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
              <Card.Footer>
                <Button onClick={() =>navigateToInventories(_id)} className='text-white, bg- 
                    dark'>Stock Update</Button>
              </Card.Footer>
            </Card>
          </CardGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
  );
};

export default Inventory;
```

***Server side code***
By the following code  I tried to fetch but in console it's say failed to fetch data.

```
 app.get('/inventory/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const id = req.params.id;
            const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
            const inventory = await inventoryCollection.findOne(query);
            res.send(inventory)
        });
```

Comment: crashes rarely happen without an error message showing a **detailed** reason for the crash

Comment: can you add the error message?

Comment: also can you add the import commands you are using it the inventory code